# Serverless yml change the arn dynamically

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, serverless, aws-serverless

I am using serverless.yml  for managing my lambda function , their are different dynamodb tables having  different ARN  for different environment based on env variable stage , how can i make this dynamic so that whenever i am changing the env from staging to productions the ARN should change according to that i.e ARN should change from 11111 to 22222

```html
service: lambda-service
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  stage: staging # value should be staging or production .. value used in appConfig.js
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${self:provider.stage}
  region: ap-south-1
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
            - dynamodb:Query
            - dynamodb:Scan
            - dynamodb:GetItem
            - dynamodb:PutItem
            - dynamodb:UpdateItem
            - dynamodb:DeleteItem
          Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-south-1:11111111:table/table-1
        
        
            
functions:
  api:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - httpApi: '*'

plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make certain parameters dynamic based on `stage` is to use Serverless Parameters: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/parameters